# How can I set the camera "far plane" in Delphi / Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The TCamera component in Delphi / Firemonkey seems to clip at 1000 units. That is, any objects more than 1000 units from the camera are not displayed/are partially displayed. Is there a way to set the "far plane" in the camera frustum to something larger than 1000? I have not been able to find any relevant settings or properties for this.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the near and far planes are hardcoded in FMX.Types3D. Wherever CreatePerspectiveForRH is called, 1 and 1000 are used. The only suggestion I have for seeing further is to scale your whole scene down.

Comment: @XylemFlow Thanks. I was worried that would be the case. I may attempt to change it right in Types3D and see if that does the trick. I don't want to because I'd have to change it each time Delphi got updated. But I also don't want to have to scale everything, making every point access more complicated.  Honestly, hard coding something like that is amateur-hour.

Comment: @XylemFlow Alternatively I may try putting a dummy object at the root scaled at 0.1 or whatever, and put my objects under that. I really only need a field about 5000 x 5000 c 5000.